# Autoincrement in Oracle(Adjust the ID sequence after deleting)

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE test
(id NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR2(30));

CREATE SEQUENCE test1_sequence
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1;

INSERT INTO test (id, name) VALUES (test1_sequence.nextval,'Jon');
INSERT INTO test (id, name) VALUES (test1_sequence.nextval,'Hello');
INSERT INTO test (id, name) VALUES (test1_sequence.nextval,'Matt');
INSERT INTO test (id, name) VALUES (test1_sequence.nextval,'Bork');
```

And suppose if I deleted one record from this table by-

```
delete from test where id='2';
```

then If I do select query-

```
select * from test;
```

then I get

```
  ID  Name    
  1    Jon    
  3    Matt
  4    Bork
```

So If I need to maintain the order of id, like as soon as I delete any data it adjusts the id automatically. So I should be getting the table as

```
ID  Name    
1    Jon    
2    Matt
3    Bork
```

Any suggestions how can I do this..

Comment: Why would you want to do that in the first place?

Comment: @Adrian, Any disadvantages of not doing it??

Comment: I agree with @Adrian. Why would you ever want to do that.  You'd also have to renumber everything else using that ID as a foreign key.

Comment: @RaihanJamal Not at all! But I can list a handful of disadvantages of **doing** it: 1. You'd have to do it every now and then 2. How would you track historical data (Client A is 3 then changes to 2, how about all other related data?) and the list would go on...

Comment: After deleting the row with id 2, they rows can still be ordered by id.  the order would be 1, 3, 4 which is correct.

Comment: In my view, you should not be ordering on PK at all. If you need a sequential list of rows, just add a analytic function like ROW_NUMBER to your query.

Comment: Yeah and also realize if you do that and delete a row, you have to lock every row ahead of it to do the update. Concurrency becomes a nightmare.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I remember correctly from articles on Ask Tom website, sequence DOES NOT guarantee that it will produce gap free numbers. So the way you are filling up your table and generating ID's will never be 100% gap free (even without deleting rows).

Here's one of the articles on that subject: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4343369880986

Also keep in mind that you are updating (what seems a) primary key column.

My suggestion is not to do it. If you need a ordered list of rows, use ROW_NUMBER and leave PK to be a surrogate key without attaching any "application meaning" to it.